# Numerical solution for a two dimensional third order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm a bit lost in all the numerous methods for solving differential equations and I would be very grateful if someone could point me to some direction.

I want to solve the following boundary conditioned differential equation:

$\vec a_1+a_2\overrightarrow{\nabla f(x,y)}+a_3\Delta f(x,y)\cdot\overrightarrow{\nabla f(x,y)} +\left[a_4+a_5\Delta f(x,y)\right]^\frac{2}{3}\cdot\overrightarrow{\nabla(\Delta f(x,y))}=0$

$a_i$ - are constants
$\nabla$ - is the gradient
$\Delta$ - is the Laplace operator

This equation is solved on a rectangular domain. let say for a start that the boundaries are:
$f(0,y)=0$ ; $f(x,0)=0$ ; $f(x,a)=C_1$ ; $\nabla f(b,y)=C_2$

$(a,b)$ - Is the corner of the rectangle and $C_1,C_2$ are known constants.

- $f$ - represents electric potential
  $\nabla f$ - represents electric field
  $\nabla^2 f$ - represents small excess charge density
- To simplify the equation I can perform a first order expansion to $\nabla^2f(x,y)$ because it is very small. Than I can solve it rather easily using finite difference method, but I really prefer not to neglect this term $\left[\nabla^2f(x,y)\right]$.

Thanks again

Comment: What is $f'(x,y)$?

Comment: Shouldn't there be partial derivatives?

Comment: You are right, ' should be the partial derivatives. I edited the post and changed ' to the del operator and gave clarifications for the function f and its derivatives for clarification.

Comment: How does that work, $∇^kf$ is a stage $k$ tensor. The Laplace operator is $\Delta f=∇^*∇f=trace(∇^2f)$. How do you combine them in that seemingly scalar expression? Perhaps it would help if you expanded on the finite difference approximations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Why is it scalar expression and not vector expression?

Without neglecting $\Delta f$ I don't know how to implement a finite difference method on such an equation.

Comment: Why is there $f'$ in the last boundary condition?

Comment: It's a mistake, I corrected it. I know the potential $f$ at three edges and the electric field at the last edge.